# Animator startDelay ignored after animation is resumed

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, animator

I'm trying to implement the pause/resume functionality for some of our Animators ( ObjectAnimators, AnimatorSets, ValueAnimators), We have very complex animations and we based some of our logic on setStartDelay.

The problem is that after pausing an animation, the delay time seems to keep running, so when i resume the animation it fires right away.

is there a way for the Animator to also consider the delay time when it's paused?

Any advise would be really helpful.

Thanks!